# Why does this bitwise operation not give same result in python and js?

Tags: javascript, python, bit-manipulation

**In python:**

```
crc = -1 ^ int("0x806567CB",16)
print crc
```

*results in:*   -2154129356.

**In javascript:**

```
<html>

<body onload="test()"></body>
<script>
function test()
{

crc = -1 ^ ("0x806567CB");    
document.write(crc);
}
</script>

</html>
```

*results in:* 2140837940.

Why the difference?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of obfuscating code here. Why `"0x" + '806567CB'` and not `0x806567CB`? Why the right bit shift non-op on `-1`?

Comment: You don't really even need the XOR. The question is basically, "why does the expression `-0x806567CB` produce different values in python and javascript?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has arbitrary precision integers and therefore the number `0x806567CB` is just a regular positive integer.

Javascript instead converts numbers to 32-bit integers when doing bitwise operations. What javascript is giving you is the same Python result but truncated to 32 bits.

To get the same result in Python:

```
 x = x & 0xFFFFFFFF   # Keep only 32 bits
 if x >= 0x80000000:
     # Consider it a signed value
     x = -(0x100000000 - x)
```

Comment: How can I emulate js then? I'm try to build a cookie from this.